# groovy method's parameters number

Tags: groovy

In Groovy Is it possible to passe any parameters to groovy method?

for example:

```
myMethod(String a)
myMethod(String a, Int b)
myMethod(String a, Int b, date c)

def myMethod (???){
def myHashMap = [:]
//put elements in myHashMap (?)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No idea what you're asking but you can pass any sort of parameters to:

```
def myMethod( ...params ) {
  println "Called with : ${params.collect { "$it" }.join( ', ' )}"
}

myMethod( 10 )
myMethod( 'woo', 10 )
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to define your method signature as follows:

```
def myMethod(String a, Integer b=0, Date c = new Date) // default values for optional params

def myMethod(String a, Integer b=0, Date c = new Date) {
     def myHashMap = [:]
     ...
}
```